# Compile obfuscated error

Tags: basic4android

when I 'm compiling my project in B4A using the obfuscated option, I get the below error:

```
Compiling generated Java code.          Error
B4A line: 6
Dim ActivityResponse As String: ActivityResponse=\
javac 1.6.0_26
src\adamioan\cinemattica\com\actmovie.java:1192: array dimension missing
_vvvvv3 = BA.__b (new byte[] }, 680010);
                             ^
1 error
```

This error occures only with the obfuscated option; debug and simple compilation work great.
Why is this happening?

Comment: Are you using 1.8 beta or final version?

Comment: Can you post the B4A code of that line?

Comment: @Manu: I 'm using B4A enterprise final 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bug in the obfuscation feature related to empty strings. It will be fixed for the next update. Note that there is no need to assign empty strings as this is the default value. So for now just remove the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both, it was my mistake. In the Process Globals I declared the variable ActivityResponse and in the same line I set this to "".

```
Dim ActivityResponse as String: ActivityResponse = ""
```

That was the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Your code is actually correct (though it is redundant). This is a bug and it will be fixed...